# Intel and AT&T assembly syntax highlighting in TextMate

Tags: assembly, textmate, intel, highlight, att

How do I get Intel and AT&T assembly syntax highlighting in TextMate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this answer is helpful.

> GAS-x86 (or x64) highlighting scheme
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956793/3920448

Open `Package Control`, type `gasx` to find the package.

Answer (score 4):

Can this be of use?

[x86 Assembly.tmbundle](https://github.com/foxostro/x86-assembly-textmate-bundle/tree/master/x86%20Assembly.tmbundle/)

I'm not familiar with assembly syntax, so I can't test it apart from trying the examples on the Wikipedia article (that, for what matters, seem to work).

Comment: future viewers: my fork has better highlighting when targeting NASM -  [get it here](https://github.com/lunixbochs/x86-assembly-textmate-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any existing bundles for any kind of assembly language, so you would have to write your own.  [Chapter 12 of the TextMate manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars) covers the basics of creating a grammar for highlighting which should get you started, plus there are a fair number of bundles out there you can look at to get ideas.

Comment: I found something on Google ( first match on http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=textmate+intel+assembly+bundle ) but the link doesn't work...
Writing my own bundle seems a bit too complex...