# Is there syntax highlighting for assembly in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: text, assembly, ide, syntax-highlighting

I'm unable to highlight my assembly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, but since Sublime Text 2 can read Textmate language definition files (.tmLanguage files), you could easily add support to Assembly by copying something like https://github.com/foxostro/x86-assembly-textmate-bundle to your "Packages" directory (`C:\Users\hugo\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages` on my Win7).

Comment: And I can recommend to check out [my fork](https://github.com/13xforever/x86-assembly-textmate-bundle) of it, as I found out this project to be very outdated even for x86 instruction set.

Comment: If you know basics of XML you can alter that to add additional commands. I've added support for strings and dw.

Comment: In Mac OS I placed it here: /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages.  I then edited the x86 Assembly.tmLanguage and added <string>hla</string> to the fileTypes array to support HLA syntax highlighting.

Comment: I guess this is supposed to be GAS syntax? I think I remember not liking this due to it not covering x64 and missing a huge number of macros/preprocessor stuff. I made [a more up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956793/) one.

Answer (score 39):

For MIPS:

In Sublime Text, just go to Preferences > Package Control > install packages.  Once there search for `mips-syntax` and hit enter on the result.

Once it installs you should be able to select MIPS as the syntax highlighting for whatever file you're editing.

Edit: Of course, this does assume that your Sublime has Package Control. You can get package control to do this and more at: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control.

Answer (score 10):

I've found another one [Assembly x86 syntax definition (NASM)](https://github.com/Nessphoro/sublimeassembly).

It seems that this guy had done a huge amount of work, and keeps the syntax updated. At least at the time of writing the last change was 9 days ago.

He has also [this post on Sublime forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11327).

Answer (score 10):

**GNU Assembler (GAS) x86(-64) syntax:**

I know there's a chosen answer, but for anyone else who comes here in the future, you have to specify which syntax/machine you want. Assembly comes in a *lot* of different flavors for a lot of different machines. Other answers have given Intel x86, NASM, SPARC, and MIPS. When I visited this page back in 2014, I was looking for a good GAS/AT&T syntax def for x86, which I never found.

So naturally, I made [my own](https://github.com/calculuswhiz/Assembly-Syntax-Definition). It's really an x64 highlighter, but of course that includes x86 too.

It's also on Package Control. To find it, type "gasx" into the search field.

I also ported it over to [Atom](https://github.com/calculuswhiz/atom-GAS-x86_64-highlighter) (available from Atom packages), [Vim](https://github.com/calculuswhiz/vim-GAS-x86_64-highlighter), and [Gedit](https://github.com/calculuswhiz/gedit-GAS-x86_64-highlighter).

Answer (score 4):

Like others, I noticed a distinct lack of SPARC syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2, so I rolled my own. It's fully functional, and has its [very own entry](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SPARC%20Assembly) in Will Bond's [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). With Package Control installed, you can install my package in Sublime via `Ctrl+Shift+P -> Package Control: Install Package -> SPARC Assembly Syntax`.

Complete install instructions and usage tips are available on the [Github project page](https://github.com/ProtractorNinja/SPARC-sublime).

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but there is this one: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/NASM%20x86%20Assembly

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was for Sublime 2, but if you want a nice highlighter
I'm using the **MasmAssembly on Sublime 3** and found that its quite good. It highlights even **ZMMs registers and the lastests SSE instructions**.

You can install it using the package control plugin, nevetheless here is the repository: 
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MasmAssembly

Answer (score 0):

AVR-ASM is also available!

See answer by Bitwise but search for AVR-ASM.

I had to install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) first:

Win/Linux: `<Ctrl + Shift + P>`
Mac: `<Cmd + Shift + P>`

...then type "Install Package Control" and press `<Enter>`